# Switching between posts in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have created a sidebar.php-file with the code;

```
<section class="sidomeny"><p class="Senastenytt2"><?php get_search_form();?></p></section><!--Slut på sidomeny-->

<div id="nyhet3">

  <?php

    query_posts('category = all');

    if (have_posts()) :

       while (have_posts()) : ?>

             <?php the_post(); ?>

         <p class="datum2"><?php the_time('Y-m-d'); ?></p>
         <p class="Nyhetsrubrik3"><a style="orange"; href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>

     <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
          <p class="textnyhet2"></p>


      <?php 
        endwhile;
        endif;
      ?>

</div><!--Slut på Nyhet3-->
```

And now I would like to add the function that if you press the sidebar news section, the "textnyhet2" section will get updated with the news you clicked on. That is how it's working now.

But the problem is that the sidebar vanished whenever you click on one of those "latest news" links. So what I need help with is to edit the sidebar.php-file so the "latest news" function with links is still there so you don't have to go back one page whenever you would like to read about another post.

Im not sure how to do this. If it's php involved or if you can do it by simple visiting the posts/pages section in wordpress.

Would be grateful if anyone could help me. If I have forgotten any necassary information please tell me and I will the post.

Thanks!

```
<?php
get_header();
?>
<section class="textinnehall">
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) :
      the_post();
      the_content();
   endwhile;
endif;?>
</section>
<section class="sidomeny">
<?php
get_sidebar(); ?>
</section>
<?php
get_footer(); 
?>
```

This is my page.php file. Don't know if it will be to any help. But the sidebar is already active.

Comment: Don't use `query_posts` as it should not be used, as directed by the codex. Use WP_Query in this instance. Better and cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the sidebar is not called in your single page.

you need to have the same design in your themes single.php page(As per twenty ten theme standard).

```
<p class="Nyhetsrubrik3"><a style="orange"; href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
```

The href `<?php the_permalink() ?>` takes the post to single page for full view

Just call the sidebar in your theme's single page.

Comment: I've applied the theme myself and I don't have a "single.php" page. Though I have one "page.php" perhaps it's the same?
Thanks for answer!:)
Added some code to the first post from my page.php file.